# Why are some http-headers ignored in camel (e.g. Cache-control)?

Tags: java, http, http-headers, apache-camel

I wanted to set the cache-control header for a soap message using the camel http-endpoint like this:

```
   .setHeader("Cache-Control", constant("no-cache"))
   .to(http(targetUrl))
```

But camel ignores this header which is probably due to HttpHeaderFilterStrategy being set by default, which looks like this:

```
public class HttpHeaderFilterStrategy extends DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy {

public HttpHeaderFilterStrategy() {
    initialize();
}

protected void initialize() {
    getOutFilter().add("content-length");
    getOutFilter().add("content-type");
    getOutFilter().add("host");
    // Add the filter for the Generic Message header
    // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.5
    getOutFilter().add("cache-control");
    getOutFilter().add("connection");
    getOutFilter().add("date");
    getOutFilter().add("pragma");
    getOutFilter().add("trailer");
    getOutFilter().add("transfer-encoding");
    getOutFilter().add("upgrade");
    getOutFilter().add("via");
    getOutFilter().add("warning");

    setLowerCase(true);
```

I found an answer here in stackoverflow which says that a workaround is setting your own HeaderFilterStrategy to overwrite HttpHeaderFilterStrategy.
I assume it will work but before doing this I wanted to ask if there is a good reason that some http-headers can't be set, because right now none come to my mind.

Thank you !

Comment: if you are consuming api before this part, remember that headers are removed on every api consumption